# Cannot get git completion to work on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: git, bash, macos

I want git commands to autocomplete when I press `TAB` twice. Here are the instructions from the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks)

> If you want to set up Git to automatically have Bash shell completion
>   for all users, copy this script to the
>   /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d directory on Mac systems or to the
>   /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory on Linux systems. This is a
>   directory of scripts that Bash will automatically load to provide
>   shell completions.

I have followed these instructions but git completion is not working. One thing to note is my computer only had the `/opt` directory. It was empty so I had to create all the subfolders (`local/etc/bash_completion.d`). My hunch is the book is outdated and that I actually need to place the script in a different location. I have also tried to put the script in the `/etc/bash_completion.d` directory which it recommends for linux systems. Neither locations work.

This could also be a highSierra problem because I also have a machine that's running Yosemite and git completion works fine.

Comment: Unrelated, but I personally switched to zsh (or in fact [oh my zsh](http://ohmyz.sh)) which has some cool features for git. In any case the autocomplete works perfectly for my on zsh / highSierra.